# What does "Run the Place" mean in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Eventually, he worked his way up to assistant manager. But the Dooleys **ran the place** as if they were kings and he was their servant.

Does it mean the Dooleys took his place?

Comment: The Dooleys were leading the operation. They were the big bosses and everyone had to bow to them.

Comment: u mean the Dooleys assigned him?

Comment: "Run", in this sense, means to exercise control.

Comment: 'The place' here means 'the business'; the sentence describes how the owners organised it.

Comment: It's idiomatic. Most if not all English natives will have heard it and be familiar with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ran** [TDF](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/run) one of many senses

> To cause to function; operate:

As in:

> But the Dooleys operated the place as if they were kings and he was
>   their servant.

The Dooley operated as 'imperial' employers and treated their employee as a servant.